# Make flex items wrap after third item on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have set a row of thumbnails using flex and this works fine, they are centered vertically on desktop. How can I have on mobile screen 3 images in the first row and 2 images in the second row? Images in second row should be aligned to the left.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/220" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/250" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/240/100" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250/220" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/270" alt="" />
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akLbzV

Comment: Flexbox does not have that option. And there is no clear in flexbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can try is to adjust the width of each flex item in your media query, so that three items are forced into the first row, and two items are forced into subsequent rows.

You can do this using the `flex`, `flex-basis` or `width` properties. However, `width` worked best in your code, probably because the image elements have inherent sizing.

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLGNXd?editors=1100)

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img { padding: 10px 5px; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  div { flex-wrap: wrap;  }
  img:nth-child(-n + 3) { width: 33.33%; } /* targets first three elements only */
  img:nth-child(n + 4)  { width: 50%; } /* targets all elements except first three */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/220" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/250" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/240/100" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250/220" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/270" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/260/140" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/210/200" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `width` or `flex-basis` (for ex. because your elements have varying widths and you need `space-between`) and you're OK with using extra `<div/>`, you can do something like this:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/220" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/250" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/240/100" alt="" />
  <div class="flex-break"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250/220" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/270" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-wrap {
   width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  display: none;
}
```

It's not the most beautiful solution but it solves the problem.